# How to return request body in a field in response using Wiremock

Tags: wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I have a JSON request as below:

```
{
    "fieldOne": 12345,
    "fieldTwo": 1234,
    "fieldThree": "2019-12-05T12:32:42.323905",
    "fieldFour": "string",
    "fieldFive": 5432,
    "fieldSix": "string",
    "fieldSeven": "string",
    "fieldEight": "string"
}
```

I need to send the complete request JSON object inside a field in response. My Wiremock stub JSON is,

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "urlPath": "/endpoint"
},
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "jsonBody": {
      "request": "{{{request.body}}}", //If I remove quotes here then I get error so I added the quotes
      "anotherField": "string"
    },
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    },
    "transformers": ["response-template"]
  }
}
```

How can I send request body in a field in response?.

I now get error:

```
    Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): 
has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value\n at [Source: (
```

## Edit:-

I was using wiremock `2.19.0` version which is causing this issue. I upgraded the version to `2.21.0` and now the issue is resolved

But in the response I still have the below problem where the request body is within double quotes which is an invalid JSON. Response:-

```
{
    "request": "{ //Here the double quotes should not be present before curly brace
        "fieldOne": 12345,
        "fieldTwo": 1234,
        "fieldThree": "2019-12-05T12:32:42.323905",
        "fieldFour": "string",
        "fieldFive": 5432,
        "fieldSix": "string",
        "fieldSeven": "string",
        "fieldEight": "string"
    }",
    "anotherField": "string"
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/issues/891

Comment: one option is to retrieve each field in the request json using `jsonPath` handlebar helper like this:- `{ "request": { "fieldOne": {{jsonPath request.body '$.fieldOne'}}, "fieldTwo": 1234 }, "anotherField": "string" }` but even in this case this will work for string but not working for number

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76455655/wiremock-how-to-include-request-json-body-into-the-response-body/76470633#76470633 This answer helped me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `body` instead of `jsonBody`. Then the response message(the content present within double quotes in body) can be formatted in whatever way required.

This will work with wiremock 2.19.0 version as well

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "urlPath": "/endpoint"
},
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "body": "{\"request\": {{{request.body}}}, \"anotherField\": \"string\" }",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    },
    "transformers": ["response-template"]
  }
}
```